# Keras: Predict with generator and get result table

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, imagedatagenerator

I have a keras model trained to classify images. Since I want to predict a lot of new images (about 100k) I think the usage of a generator is the fastest way.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Set up my generator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    r"C:\new_data",
    target_size=(260, 180),
    batch_size=100,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    class_mode="categorical",
)

predicted_elements = model.predict(test_generator, batch_size=10, verbose="auto", steps=None, callbacks=None)
```

What I need is a table, to see which image belongs to which (predicted) class. Like:

| filename | predicton |
| --- | --- |
| 1.jpg | coffee |
| 2.jpg | car |
| 3.jpg | plane |
| ... | ... |

Edit:
My Question is: How can I create this table?
The generator resorts the images anyway. Also I don't know how to get the names.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: You are both right. I edited the post. The question is: How can I create the desired table?